# Display android calendar view on top of other activity

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I've been looking for how to display calendar view on top of other activities. It looks like how bootstrap modal work for the web. When you click on a button to display calendar, your activities are still in the background and you calendar is displayed on top of it. So any body know how to do it or any resource?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So actually I found some source for it. I think It's solved my problem and for your information here is the link 
http://www.androidviews.net/2013/03/timessquare-for-android/